# How to import XML by piping from command line?

Tags: xml, sqlite, csv, command-line, xml2

I'm converting from XML to CSV with `xml2 | 2csv` tool, then call `.import` to SQLite. I don't want to generate a CSV file, but want to pipe the converted file from `xml2` to the `.import` query.

I have tags.xml:

```xml
<tags>
  <row Id="1" TagName=".net" Count="316293" ExcerptPostId="3624959" WikiPostId="3607476" />
  <row Id="2" TagName="html" Count="1116853" ExcerptPostId="3673183" WikiPostId="3673182" />
  <row Id="3" TagName="javascript" Count="2343663" ExcerptPostId="3624960" WikiPostId="3607052" />
</tags>
```

So instead of doing this conversion:

```
xml2 | 2csv row @Id @TagName @Count @ExcerptPostId @WikiPostId < tags.xml > tags.csv
```

Then importing to database from command line:

```
sqlite3 mydb.db -csv ".import tags.csv tags"
```

I want something like this from the command line:

```
sqlite3 mydb.db -csv ".import <xml2 | 2csv command> tags"
```

My XML file is around 100GB so I don't want to materialize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do the same with a 90 GB file, here is how I import it:

```
xml2 < Posts.xml | 2csv row @Id @PostTypeId @AcceptedAnswerId @CreationDate \
            @Score @ViewCount @Body @OwnerUserId @LastEditorUserId \
            @LastEditorDisplayName @LastEditDate @LastActivityDate \
            @Title @Tags @AnswerCount @CommentCount @FavoriteCount \
            @CommunityOwnedDate @ContentLicense | \
sqlite3 stack.db -csv ".import /dev/stdin posts"
```

The conversion with `xml2` happens via pipes, and the stdout of `2csv` is passed directly into the stdin of `sqlite3`